# Why don't we always use very small learning?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

I knew large learning rate and small learning rate difference (figure below).

[image]

I'm confusing that if we have time, why we don't just use very small learning rate because small learning can finally go to the minimum.

Or, Are there any disadvantages of using very small learning rate? ( except time spending )

Comment: This question is probably suited for https://stats.stackexchange.com/ as there is nothing here related to programming

Comment: Possibly relevant - https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/410/choosing-a-learning-rate

Comment: Because we don't have time. If you use too small a rate, training may *never* converge. "Small" is relative and what you consider "small" may well be too large for the actual training data. With a fixed rate you'd have to experiment until you found a rate that actually works. With an adaptive rate, you don't have to worry so much

Comment: The "only" disadvantage of a very small learning rate is indeed that the training will be slower. It is not as easy as saying "I'll just wait", though. Obviously, there is the resource spending, but also the fact that it may be harder to tell whether the training is reaching a local minimum or if it is just too slow. More sophisticated algorithms use adaptive learning rates and momentum to compute more effective parameter updates.

Comment: Ok I got it. Thank you so much!